# Looking for custom script in Adobe DTM data element?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I am trying to capture HTML text value in DTM. There is a article tag which has the detail of the card. Once the User clicks on the card, the name of card (h1) tag will be reported. Below mentioned my code snippet.

```html
<article class="mu-item">
  <a href="#">
    <div>
      <h1>This is a test text for tracking</h1>
      <p>This was the day when the South Stand at Old Trafford, the stadium where he played around half of his 758 matches for United, was officially renamed in his honour before his beloved Reds took on Everton in the Barclays Premier League.<br><br>
</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</article>
```

I have tried creating event based rule with data element but nothing is working fine.
Can anyone please provide the right direction. should i have to create a data element or not. What should i define in my data element. do i have to use DTM custom scripts.

Comment: what is the actual problem? Is the click event working but you are having trouble capturing that value? Or is the click event rule not working either?

Comment: also, what is the visitor actually clicking on.. are they clicking on that you are trying to hook event based rule to? Is it that `<a>` wrapped  stuff in your post, or something else?

Comment: Hey crayon, my bad for not providing more details. So in my actual implementation i have a image and title (h1) associated with it in page. There are various images in a page. Once the user clicks the image, it should capture the image title. The structure is similar to the example code i have provided above. What is currently happening now once i click on the text, it is not capturing the value of title (h1) in the evar. i have tried it using jquery. $(this).parents(“article”).children(“h1”).text(); but still couldnt get the result. sme post are suggesting no need to create a data element

Comment: Some posts are suggesting no need to create data element, so i am kind of confused how i should i go.

Comment: hmm have you verified the actual event based rule is triggering though? because the jquery seems legit at face value and works by itself on sandbox

Comment: I checked using adobe pulse debugger and it does gets updated once i click on the text. but doesnt assign h1 value to an evar. Just to be more clear let me just provide what i have done so far. I created an event based rule with event type = click, tag = article.mu-item, rule condition criteria ={ var articletitle = $(this).parents(“article”).children(“h1”).text();
_satellite.setVar('article title',articletitle);
return true; }, and assigned "%article title% in the evar. I have not created any data element. Is this the correct approach ??

Comment: yeah at face value that should work. have you tried `console.log(articletitle);` in your condition to see if it actually has a value? Also, this may not be an issue anymore but in the early days of DTM I've had mixed results with using spaces in data element names so I've avoided it since. Try using `_satellite.setVar('article_title',articletitle)` and then `%article_title%`

Comment: also, just making sure no stone unturned.. you are using `%article_title%` in a *field* later on, not custom code box? because if you are popping it in a custom code box (actual js code), you need to use `_satellite.getVar('article_title')` not % syntax

Comment: this one is really confusing now. I tried using ur suggestion for console.log(articletitle); but it returned =  _satellite.getVar(articletitle); Uncaught ReferenceError: articletitle is not defined(…). which means the jquery i used might not be correct. I have already tried 2 queries - 1) $(this).parents('article').children('h1').text(); 2) $(this).find('h1').text();... still no luck. CRAYY just one question, the flow i mentioned above regarding not using a data element and defining tag in event based rule as tag = article.mu-item is correct ryt ???? please help

Comment: okay so if your event rule's **Element Tag or Selector** is "article.mu-item" then your first jQuery thing won't work, because `this` refers to the article tag so `.parents()` is trying to look for an article tag above that.  Your 2nd one should work  though. Do you have "all events to bubble" checked?

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of your event based rule? The top part of it and the conditions section

Comment: I knew something was wrong about 1st jquery. I have uploaded a screen shot of the event based rule. Since i couldnt upload it here so i have done it in http://imgur.com/. below mentioned is the URL, Let me know if you are able to see that. Image URL - http://imgur.com/b5GGG9G

Comment: Also while assigning evar, i am using %article_title%. I tried to use your suggestion for using _satellite.getvar, but it didnt worked too.

Comment: your image doesn't show everything.  Do you have "Allow events on child elements to bubble" checked? If yes, then I don't really know what else to say at this point.  It definitely works on a sandbox page. So there must be something else going on on your site

Comment: Yes it is checked..Just for reference i have the code on a page and running locally through IIS with localhost. Although i dont think so that this could be an issue. because my page load event rule is getting fired properly.

Comment: so `var articletitle = $(this).find('h1').text();console.log('articletitle: ',articletitle);` that doesn't show the article title either (in js console)?

Comment: No Cray it doesnt work. I even tried creating a data element with the code u provided, returning articletitle and then refrencing it in evar assignation.. but it didnt worked...

Comment: okay, in your condition box, do `console.log(this);`  what does it output

Comment: what should i assign in evar ?

Comment: if i use console.log(this); it gives me my article class code.. URL - http://imgur.com/a/1kaUv

Comment: okay. then it doesn't make sense that `var articletitle = $(this).find('h1').text();console.log('articletitle: ',articletitle);` returns nothing in the js console. Are you sure you have jQuery installed and it's available when the event is triggered?

Comment: forget about your evar for now. clearly there's issue with getting the value in the first place. one step at a time

Comment: OK by "jQuery installed and it's available" do u mean here including <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> in the source code.

Comment: yes. is that above your dtm tag? also holy crap that's ancient. it's possible that version doesn't even support some of that syntax. can you update it to a more recent version?

Comment: okay well i tried my sandbox with that version of jQuery and it still works so that's not it

Comment: var articletitle = $(this).find('h1').text();console.log('articletitle: ',articletitle); this doesnt work still  tried with version of jquery. included this code in custom criteria...

Comment: okay since you said `console.log(this)` shows your article html, here is a jsfiddle showing the jQuery string works fine https://jsfiddle.net/qua858yp/

Comment: so i really don't know what to say at this point except there must be some other factor on your local environment

Comment: Hmm even i am confused about this. Not really sure why i am not able to capture h1 value atleast. Anyways Thanks for your help Cray. If you have any inputs please let me know..... your posts are really informative.

Comment: hey how about for shits and grins you put this into your condition box:     `var articletitle=this.querySelector('h1').innerText;console.log('articletitle: ',articletitle);` what does it output (in the js console)?

Comment: Hey CRAY the coder.. Not sure how i can thank you much for this. This actually WORKEDDD... what i did was updated the condition var articletitle=this.querySelector('h1').innerText;
_satellite.setVar('articletitle',articletitle);
return true; and in evar i assigned %articletitle%. This thing populates the title of the article being clicked in the evar. Not very sure why the jquery logic wasnt working. but this did worked,.... Thanks allot

Comment: okay cool.  Then it sounds like it is indeed a problem with your jQuery library. Maybe you have a `.noConflict()` that changes the namespace from `$` to something else. Or maybe you have something else on your site overwriting `$`. Or maybe you don't actually have the file in the location you point to, etc.

Comment: also now that you've got it working, fyi, you mentioned not using a data element for this.. well you are in fact using a data element for this. You're just creating an on-the-fly one instead of in the main data element config area.

Comment: Oki cray will keep this in mind. just one question here, is it a normal practice of creating data element on fly. i mean we might have more unusual requirements for tracking, should we follow that method.

Comment: The way you have it now is the only way you can do it ATM, because DTM does not currently pass a reference to `this` to data elements created in the config area

Answer (score 0):

You can do that creating a new "data element" and using the css selector type, the, put the CSS Selector Chain

in this case I will use the following css selector for example.

```
.mu-item div h1
```

Now select "text" in the "get the value of" option, and save changes.

It should work.